# How does python understand when we give two comparison operators in while loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
list2 = [6,7,8,9,10,11]
new_list = list()

i = 0
while i<5 and i<6:
    new_list.append((list1[i],list2[i]))
    i += 1

print(new_list)
```

The code works, and the output is:

```
[(1, 6), (2, 7), (3, 8), (4, 9), (5, 10)]
```

However, I just wonder how Python works when we give two greater/smaller options in the while loop. In the case above, I've defined both `i<5` and `i<6`, but how does it work inside and how does the program understand `i<5` belongs to `list1` and `i<6` belongs to `list2`? When I change the while loop as `while i<6:` I get `IndexError: list index out of range`.

Comment: `while i<5`  should be enough  -- `i` can't be less than `5` without also being less than `6`. However, `while i<6` breaks because it allows `list1[5]` which is out of range. Also, look into `zip()`: `new_list = list(zip(list1,list2))`

Comment: zip if lists have the same size

Comment: @andreis11 or if they don't have the same size, in which case it behaves like the OPs code.

Comment: That's correct! Don't know why I thought that it would give an error (not eq len) instead of just not passing the 'unpaired' element. my bad

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Allow me to make a little correction to your statement:
Python does not understand that `i<5` should belong only to `list1` and `i<6` to `list2`.

In fact what is happening is the following:

- you define one single variable `i` when writing `i=0`
- in `while i<5 and i<6:` you combine two comparison operations:

  1. is `i` smaller than `5`
  2. is (the same) `i` smaller than `6`
- inside the while-loop you use that single variable `i` as index both for `list1` and `list2` then you increment `i` by `1`.

When writing only `while i<6:` what happens is that for `i=5` the loop still runs and your code tries to get `list1[5]` which does not exist, as `list1` is of size 5 and thus the last element is accessed with `list1[4]`. If you simply type `list1[5]` in the console you will get an `IndexError`, the exact same error you get when removing the `i<5` from your `while`-condition.

---

If you want to combine several lists into a single list, python has a built-in function for this: [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)
If, like in your case, the lists are of various size and you do not want to loose any elements then, also in this case, python has you covered with the [`zip_longest()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) method from the [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#module-itertools) module.

Here is how this would look:

```py
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
list2 = [6,7,8,9,10,11]
new_list = [*zip(list1,list2)]  # or list(zip(list1,list2))
print(new_list)
>>> [(1, 6), (2, 7), (3, 8), (4, 9), (5, 10)]


# without loosing elements:
from itertools import zip_longest
new_list = [*zip_longest(list1,list2)]
print(new_list)
>>> [(1, 6), (2, 7), (3, 8), (4, 9), (5, 10), (None, 11)]
```

As you can see, the last element of `list2` us missing when using `zip`.
With `zip_longest`, however, it is still there and the 'missing' element from `list1` is completed with `None`.

Hoped that helped to clarify a few things.